# A synonym for "soft" with a negative connotation

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym for *soft*, as in the opposite of *coarse* or *crass*. The context is a young French woman in Nazi Germany who asks a shopkeeper for something to catch a mouse in her house. The German shopkeeper says "Oh, you French people are so **soft**, just say that you're looking for something to kill the mouse with."

Any suggestions? What other words would work here?

Comment: Are you looking for an insult, as in 'mealy-mouthed' (see Josh61) or do you want a neutral (or even complimentary) term?

Comment: Given your context, “wimpy” or “wimpish” would be anachronistic, but they’d work in post-1965ish dialogues.

Comment: I think that *soft* fits the context perfectly. :/

Comment: Would that be *coarse*?

Comment: I agree with @Anonym - in contemporary English, "you people are so soft" absolutely reads as negative or insulting. I can't say offhand whether it fits the period setting, though.

Comment: Just thought I'd state my agreement with "anonym" and "recognizer"; the word "soft" itself when applied to a person already has a negative connotation.

Comment: I looked at synonyms of "pacifist" and *irenic*is another option to add to those already offered.

Answer (score 23):

How about **delicate**?  Mealy-mouthed (from @Josh61 's answer) conveys what you want more precisely, but delicate has that soft negative connotation.

> fragile; easily damaged; frail. From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/delicate?s=t)

An alternative if you don't like delicate could be **squeamish**:

> easily nauseated or disgusted.  From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/squeamish?s=t)

Comment: Delicate could definitely work.

Comment: Squeamish seems to be the best word, at least to my ear.

Comment: @delliottg: this ought to be an answer.

Comment: Squeamish is not a synonym for soft...

Comment: I would place **delicate** and **squeamish** in bold type, or embed the links in those two words instead of writing "From here" which means nothing really, or refer directly to the source by its name.

Answer (score 9):

**"tender"** has the connotation of being gentle and soft.

"Oh, you French people are so **tender**, just say that you're looking for something to kill the mouse with."

> - [tender](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tender) (adj)  marked by, responding to, or expressing the softer emotions, showing care.

Comment: Reversed the drive-by downvote. No reason was given, and besides I like this answer :-)

Comment: Not my downvote - but "tender" tends(!) to have a positive, or at least neutral, connotation (but the question asks for a negative one).

Comment: It depends on intonation.  It can a negative connotation if it sounds like mockery.

Answer (score 9):

One of the senses of **precious** may work:

> 4. Affectedly dainty or overrefined: *precious mannerisms*.

{[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/precious)}

though this obviously covers an affected attitude.

If the person is genuinely soft, the dialect term **nesh** would often be used conversationally in the UK:

> *nesh* adjective
>
> dialect
>
> (Especially of a person) weak and delicate; feeble

{[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nesh)}

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Though I agree that the dictionary definition works, "Precious" on its own would have too many other connotations and would confuse my readers. If I said "you French are so precious" - that could sound positive. I don't think too many people would know what "nesh" is. I need something more mainstream.

Comment: @llanysong: Actually "precious" works really well here - a native speaker will understand perfectly from the context. Agree that "nesh" is a bit, well, *niche*...

Comment: Is _nesh_ nicher than _namby-pamby_?

Answer (score 7):

I think [mealy-mouthed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mealy-mouthed) may fit in your context:

> - Afraid to speak frankly or straightforwardly:
>     mealy-mouthed excuses. (ODO)

Comment: +1 for mealy-mouthed; you weren't first to mention it but you gave a definition and citation.

Comment: Ah apologies; you were in fact first to answer; I just got confused!

Comment: I don't know - it doesn't imply excessive softness, tenderness, etc. The idea is that "you guys need to be tougher". "Mealy-mouthed" sounds more like "wishy-washy" to me...

Answer (score 6):

**sentimental**:

- having or arousing feelings of tenderness, sadness or nostalgia, typically in an exaggerated or self-indulgent way (Defn. 1.1)

  [Source:[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)]
- weakly emotional; mawkishly susceptible or tender
  (Defn. 3)

  [Source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com)]

Comment: +1, especially for bringing **[mawkish](https://books.google.com/books?id=yXY0yQnvmmUC&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=%22a+mawkish+person%22&source=bl&ots=LfbeNlcylk&sig=FSgCTzKJI86GUYURGF9OJ8k444U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAWoVChMI_7aNiqnCxwIViD4-Ch3WRQ7L#v=onepage&q=%22a%20mawkish%20person%22&f=false)** to the table!

Comment: Thanks @PapaPoule  as you have found such a good definition for *mawkish*, please feel free to post as an answer, if you so wish:)

Comment: Thanks, you're too kind, but I wasn't even sure of its meaning until looking it up after seeing it in your nice answer! (anyway, I've already given one 'great' answer and I certainly wouldn't want to attract all the positive attention it's getting away from it by adding another one!)

Answer (score 6):

`Dainty` and `Prissy` come to mind.

`Weak`, `Babies`, `Cowards` would also definitely fit. Cowards would have historical context as the general view of the French by Germans of that time period. These of course are more straight insults instead of just implied ones.

`Pussyfooted` would also fit, though I am unsure how insulting this is historically.

> MW: **pussyfoot** verb pussy·foot \ˈpu̇-sē-ˌfu̇t\ 
>   to avoid making a definite decision or stating a definite opinion because of fear, doubt, etc.

Finally `minced` as in mince words (mincing?)

> Dictionary.com: mince [mins] verb 
>   2. to soften, moderate, or weaken (one's words), especially for the sake of decorum or courtesy.
>   3. to perform or utter with affected elegance.
>   5. to walk or move with short, affectedly dainty steps.
>   6. Archaic. to act or speak with affected elegance.

Comment: Upvote for `cowards` as particularly appropriate and poetic within a Nazi-occupied France context, if you wish to emphasize this underlying point.

Answer (score 4):

I think ***[squeamish](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/squeamish)*** is the adjective you're looking for, as in: "*Oh, you French people are so squeamish, just say that you're looking for something to kill the mouse with.*"

Now whether or not there's a German word for squeamish might create a problem, but if you're writing in English, you'll get your point across appropriately.

If it were a loutish American shopkeeper, he might say:  "*Oh, you French people are such pussies, just say that you're looking for something to kill the mouse with.*"

Comment: The term *squeamish* was  [suggested by @Physics-Compute](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/268879/44619) a day ago.

Comment: I think that sqeamish is also a good possibility. I usually think of "squeamish" in the context of my wife whenever she sees an insect :).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if these are what you are looking for but "Limp", and "Shush" are what popped into my mind after first reading? :)

Comment: An answer without any supporting explanation or references is simply an opinion; I encourage you to edit your post to explain *why* you propose those terms, and to include examples, dictionary definitions, or other suitable links in support. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: I like *limp*...

Answer (score 3):

If the speaker wants to imply that the listener is overly docile and caring. Perhaps verging towards being "girly" and cowardly then the noun **sissy** could well work.

> Oh, you French people are **sissies**, just say that you're looking for something to kill the mouse with.

The fact that the German shopkeeper is saying this to a young French woman would make it, in my view, slightly less insulting than if the receiver were a male adult.

The Germans occupied France between 1940 and 1944, so it's important to use a derogatory term that would have been widely known and understood in that  period. The abbreviation for *sister*, **[sis](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sis&allowed_in_frame=0)** (n),  was first recorded in the 1650s. From 1887 it became a derogatory expression, and as an adjective, ***[sissy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sissy)*** first appeared in print in 1891.

Answer (score 2):

### Milky

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/milky):

> *informal ,  dated*
>
> Weak and compliant:
>    ‘they just talk that way to make you turn milky’

Answer (score 2):

How about "effete"? It's not an exact synonym for soft, but it strongly suggests weakness and irresoluteness. Probably more suited when addressing a male though, since one of the connotations is effeminacy.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effete

> effete
>
> adjective ef·fete \e-ˈfēt, i-\
>
> lacking strength, courage, or spirit
>
> resembling a woman

Comment: I like this one. It sounds snooty and refined, but that's not what it means at all.

Answer (score 1):

"Refined" or "genteel" would work.

"Genteel: Characterized by exaggerated or affected politeness, refinement, or respectability". http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/genteel. Originally "genteel" was used in a good sense, but in the 20th century it became ironic or deprecating.

Or, the German could use the French equivalent "gentil", which a non-French-speaking reader would probably understand.

Or, use the German "kultiviert." It sounds about right for a Nazi talking to the enemy, and non-German speakers would probably guess "cultivated" as a translation.

Comment: genteel is also what I would have used but I prefer the [US oxford][1] definition - Polite, refined, or respectable, often in an affected or ostentatious way


  [1]: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/genteel

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looking for a "soft" way for a person to tell people to not talk in "soft" ways? The shopkeeper may be telling the person to not talk "softly", but he's sure not fitting the part himself. Let the crude-ass shopkeeper be a crude-ass shopkeeper and call the person a pussy.

"Oh, you French people are such pussies, just say that you're looking for something to kill the mouse with."

Now his speech fits with how he's telling the other person to be. If "pussies" is a bit too much for you I guess you could go halfway with "pansies".

Comment: Hi Jimbo.. Essentially, this would work, but I don't think that this was how people talked in the 1940s.

Comment: @JimboJonny - What gave you the impression the OP is looking for a soft way to give the message?  Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @aparente001 - The example he gave, which was exactly as "soft" as the shopkeeper was supposedly telling the other person not to be.

Comment: @Ilanysong - I call bull. There were crass people in every period of history. Considering he's specifically telling the woman not to talk "soft", make him not a soft talker either. Fit the character's speech to his persona. What a boring read it would be to have a book where each character's speech patterns match the exact same preconceived notion of how people talked in a particular period. Make your characters individuals.

Comment: @JimboJonny - I agree, the guy should express himself rather crassly -- but I really don't see that the OP was looking with intention for soft expression.  By the way, "I call bull" is the sort of phrase that tends not to go over big on StackEchange.

Comment: @aparente001 - I call it nonetheless. :) It's a perfectly crass way to show that I think he's wrong on that. I thought it fit the mood of the answer nicely. By the way, been on StackExchange for many years. Only newer to this particular corner of it (originally on StackOverflow).

Comment: @JimboJonny - I'm not a sophisticated enough user to pay attention to numbers.  I was just surprised to see vulgar language in a comment.  I didn't figure out the comment was intended to be in character (of the crude shopkeeper).  At any rate, I believe a shopkeeper would not mince words, but using plain language isn't the same as being crass.

Comment: @aparente001 - I guess I just don't consider "bull" to be vulgar. It's kinda like "dang" or "shoot" (kid-safe versions of actual swear words). I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree on the vulgarity level of it.

Comment: @JimboJonny - Would you say, "I call bull" to your department chair?  To the department secretary?  To your grad student?  But my main point was that I think you're also off on your reading of the OP's scenario.  There's a big difference between a shopkeeper's language and a construction worker's language.

Comment: @aparente001 - In any situation where I was to communicate that I thought what they were saying was false I'd be perfectly willing to say "I call bull" to do it. Just as much as I'd be willing to say "dang it" if I dropped a paperclip. But regardless, I disagree what your main point. A shopkeeper that is specifically telling people to be blunt in their language should be blunt in theirs, and the OP's way of saying it was not blunt at all. And I think your social confines of what a particular person would or wouldn't say based on their job are narrow. People are extremely varied [...continued]

Comment: ...in any job position, they don't fit into a neat little box based on their job. A shopkeeper that is going to make a point to tell a young French girl that's trying to be polite to be more blunt/crass sounds like a pretty blunt/crass person themselves. If that overlaps into what you would consider construction worker talk then so be it. There's no one rigid way that a person in a given job will talk. People are people, not just job titles. The very fact that he's going outside of "normal" shopkeeper behavior to tell her to be blunt only makes the wording I suggest all the more believable.

Comment: I have yet to meet a crass shopkeeper.  I lived in Mexico for seven years and dealt with hundreds of proprietors of tiny shops.  Adjectives that described them tended to be things like polite, pleasant, efficient, perhaps gruff, perhaps obsequious.  Never crass.  Shopkeepers want customers to come back.  //  You know, it is possible to tell it like it is without being crass.  Anyway, I'm ready to agree to disagree here.

Comment: But hold on, are we talking about the words you suggested he use, or the words you used in this collection of comments?

Answer (score 1):

My spouse, who is German, offered **Weichei (soft-boiled egg)**.  (Note, if you don't speak German, it might look a little less weird if we pretend there's a hyphen: Weich-ei.  Literally, soft egg.)

I also looked at the all-English thesaurus for synonyms for wimp.  I've picked out some words that I am hopeful are authentic for that time period (but I can't swear to it):

**milksop** "*effeminate spiritless man," late 14c.; literal sense "piece of bread soaked in milk" attested late 15c.*  Perhaps this is too gendered.

**namby-pamby** *"weakly sentimental, insipidly pretty," 1745*.

**cream puff** *In figurative sense of "weakling, sissy," it is recorded from 1935.*

**sissy** *Meaning "effeminate man" is recorded from 1887; the adjective in this sense is from 1891.*

What I like about *cream puff* is that it goes with French cuisine.  What I don't like about it is that it doesn't seem to fit with the coarseness you're after.

-- Edit -- Added what I found at the site recommended by Mari-Lou.  I also checked some dictionaries and it seems *milksop* is indeed too gendered, but *sissy* is okay.

Comment: Etymonline will give you dates on these terms. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Probably not quite negative enough, but “you […] people are so **vague**,  just say [what you mean and mean what you say] that you're looking for something to kill the mouse with" could work.

[Vague](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vague?s=t)/adjective/#5: (of persons) not clear or definite in thought, understanding, or expression:  (Dictionary[dot]com)

Answer (score 0):

euphemism

1.

the substitution of a mild, indirect, or vagueexpression for one thought to be offensive,harsh, or blunt.

2.

the expression so substituted: “To passaway” is a euphemism for “to die.”.

I believe euphemistic works

Comment: technically yes, but in this context ? A shopkeeper who'd say "French people are so euphemistic". I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

How about *flaccid:*

flac·cid

lacking force or effectiveness.
"the flaccid leadership campaign was causing concern"

synonyms:   lackluster, lifeless, listless, uninspiring, unanimated, tame, dull, vapid

"his play seemed flaccid"

Comment: I'm not sure this fits what the OP was looking for.  OP is looking for a pejorative term that would say the French are, basically, too timid to discuss killing a mouse.

Comment: @ewormuth You should add "timid" as an proper answer

Answer (score 0):

'*Soft*' seems perfect here, but let me mention the relatively obscure/ dialect word '*nesh*'.

Its main current meaning is "sensitive to cold", i.e. not sufficiently hardy to cope with the English weather.

However, it does also have a use in terms of being *timid* or generally *weak*.

It has been deemed fit to deserve its own [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesh) page.

Answer (score 0):

> "Oh, you French people are so **soft**, just say that you're looking for something to kill the mouse with."

My favourite word here would be ***[mushy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mushy)***.

> Definition of mushy in English:
>   **adjective (mushier, mushiest)**
>
> 1 Soft and pulpy:
>   *'mushy vegetables'*
>
> 2 *informal* Excessively sentimental:
>   *'a mushy film'*
>   *'Unfortunately, it seems as if he has a compulsion to negate those brilliant pieces by introducing ill advised mushy sentimentality.'*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mushy

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a direct synonym, the work *pathetic* would work quite well in that instance. It implies a deep level of disdain, which it looks like you are trying to convey in your sentence.